# Map - Fixed iteration order

Tags: java, dictionary, iteration

Can we get data from a `Map` in some sequence or ordering which will be **fixed for every time** in Java?

Comment: use `LinkedHashMap` for insertion order or `TreeMap` for custom ordering based on `Comparator`.

Comment: Look at java collections docs

Answer (score 4):

Well in *some* maps you can. For example, any implementation of [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (e.g. [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) will return the entries sorted by key order (possibly according to a custom comparator) - although that has implications on the complexity of adding and fetching entries, of course.

Then there's [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which will always return entries in insertion order.

If you're talking about plain [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) though - no, you mustn't rely on the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LinkedHashMap` which is an ordered implementation of the `Map` interface.